# How can I disable string decoration (or however this is called) in Aptana?

Tags: aptana

When I mark a string within a php file and then type a `'`, `"`, `(` or `[`, then the marked text will not be replaced by the typed in character. Instead it well be enclosed by `'…'`, `"…"`, …

I know this is a feature, of course. But I want to turn off this feature because I don't like it. Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors` - Deselect 'Wrap selected text with matching characters'.

This used to drive me crazy too, but it has grown on me.